# SQL query many-to-many realtionship

Tags: mysql, join

So I have 4 tables:

vehicles:

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+
| id |    title    |      description       |
+----+-------------+------------------------+
|  1 | Lorem ipsum | amet coscutor lorem et |
+----+-------------+------------------------+
```

prducers:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
| id |      name       |     website     | location |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
|  1 | Porsche Zentrum | www.example.com | {json}   |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
```

vehicle_images:

```
+------------+----------+
| vehicle_id | image_id |
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        1 |
+------------+----------+
```

images:

```
+----+-------+-----+----------------------------------+
| id | title | alt |               url                |
+----+-------+-----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Foo   | Bar | https://example.com/imgs/img.jpg |
+----+-------+-----+----------------------------------+
```

`vehicles` has a many-to-many relationship with `images`. What I need as result, is a list of all vehicles, the producer-details for each vehicle and all images for each vehicle.

All I get by now, is a list of all vehicles with their corresponding dealers, but each vehicle exists as often as it has images:

```
+----+-------+---------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| id | title |  description  | dealer  | img_title |  img_url  |
+----+-------+---------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Car 1 | Description 1 | Porsche | img 1     | img-url-1 |
|  1 | Car 1 | Description 1 | Audi    | img 2     | img-url-2 |
|  2 | Car 2 | Description 2 | Audi    | img 3     | img-url-3 |
|  2 | Car 2 | Description 2 | VW      | img 4     | img-url-4 |
+----+-------+---------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

And finally my query:

```
SELECT 
v.id, v.title, v.description,
p.name AS dealer,
i.title AS img_title, i.url AS img_url
FROM vehicles v
LEFT JOIN producers p on p.id = v.producer_id
LEFT JOIN vehicle_images vi on vi.vehicle_id = v.id
LEFT JOIN images i ON vi.image_id = i.id;
```

I can't use `GROUP BY id` because of the following error-message:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #9 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'projektarbeit.i.title' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Of course I could deactivate `only_full_group_by` in my MySQL-settings, but I think this would not be the best solution.

Comment: You can either disable `only_full_group_by` and let mysql choose a random value for you, or choose the value yourself (e.g. `MAX(v.title)`).

Comment: But if you want all the images from the vehicle, it is to be expected to have a row for each image the vehicle has, and that each row have repeated data like vehicle id, vehicle title and vehicle description.

Comment: Why would you want to use GROUP BY anyway? i cannot see anything wrong with the existing result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery to get necessary result, for example:

```
SELECT vehicles.id,
       vehicles.title,
       vehicles.description,
       producers.name AS dealer,
       images.title AS img_title,
       images.url AS img_url
FROM vehicles
LEFT JOIN images ON images.image_id =
  (SELECT MAX(image_id)
   FROM vehicle_images WHERE vehicle_id = vehicles.id)
LEFT JOIN producers ON producers.id = vehicles.producer_id
```